# When I built my game in xcode all the gui textures/texts look different(unity3d)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, xcode5, guitexture

I put all these GUI textures and texts and they look the way I want in the editor but when I ran it on my iphone from xcode it looks so different. All the GUI Textures and Texts are in different sizes and places. Why did that happen? Second question, if I have to fix it, do I have make the xcode project again and summit it to itunes connect again? Thanks.

Comment: People can't see your comments until they click on the question, so asking them to hurry probably won't help get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't design your GUI with multiple screen sizes in mind.

This is a basic concept in creating a UI that most tutorials will go over, including [the documentation for the default GUI system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html).

Using absolute positions and sizes results in UI that cannot scale to other screen sizes and resolutions.

It is also common practice to provide two versions of your UI's textures, one for standard DPIs, such as those found on older Apple devices, and most computer screens, and one for ultra-high DPIs, such as those found on Retina displays.

In the editor you can get an idea of what your UI will look like with the *Game View*, which [this tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/editor/the-game-view) goes over.

Once you have fixed your UI, you will need to make a new xcode project, and you will need to resubmit it.